# How to properly query all posts created by a user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**DATABASE HIERARCHY:**

```
posts
   post1_uid
      author: user2UID
      info1
      info2
   post2_uid
      author: user1UID
      info1
      info2
users
   user1_UID
      info1
      info2
      info3
   user2_UID
      info1
      info2
      info3
```

**SITUATION:**

The user can create posts. Each post has an "author" property which holds the UID of the user who created the post.

If I want to show all posts from one user, I write in my Firebase GET request:

---

**CODE:**

```
if (childData.author == firebase().auth().currentUser.uid) {
    //Show those posts created by the current user
}
```

---

**QUESTION**

Will this be efficient if my Firebase database has millions of posts and the current user's id needs to be compared to each post's "author" property ?

If no, is there a better option ?

---

**WHAT I TRIED**:

Creating in my "users/UID/" path a "posts" node which contains the UIDs of all posts that a user created.

Like that, I iterate through a much smaller json tree (only all the posts created by the user (100)) compared to iterating through all the posts on the database (Millions) to find those who have been created by the user. But does this really affect performance ? Is the increase in data nesting worth it ?

---

**OTHER DATABASE HIERARCHY:**

```
posts
   post1_uid
      author: user1UID
      info1
      info2
   post2_uid
      author: user1UID
      info1
      info2
users
   user1_UID
      info1
      info2
      info3
      posts
         referenceUID
            post1UID
            post2UID    
   user2_UID
      info1
      info2
      info3
```

Here is the actual Database Hierarchy with some fake data to mimic the behaviour of my example.

[image]

---

**TL;DR:**

How to properly organise a Firebase Database to optimise Queries looking for all Posts created by a User ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer would be defenitly nesting post data inside each user.

Here is the main performance issue when you are filtering from the whole posts node. First of all in order to filter your current user's posts you have to run query like this `postsRef.orderByChild('author').equalTo(currentUser.uid)` as you noticed `orderByChild` is expensive operation even if you are using index on the `author` it would be expensive for million records.

The cons of second approach is that you are duplicating post entries, but that is okay for nosql databases, you just have to be careful when updating all your duplicates every time some changes happen.